# Blazor hybrid template app not starting with .Net8

Tags: .net-8.0, blazor-hybrid

Since .Net8 has been released I wanted to create a new Blazor Hybrid app using the template provided in Visual Studio Community version 17.8.4.
The project compiles but never displays and then stops with a warning.
[image]
I followed the link and installed
[image]

But the issue remains, I cannot use Blazor Hybrid with .Net8.
It works fine with .Net7.

I'm on Windows 10 with the latests updates.

What could be the reason for this behaviour?